# Error "does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm getting one error while building the asp.net mvc solution, but I am able to get the datatable with data, but don't know why im getting this error. Maybe I need to add the LINQ reference somewhere.

Getting near `Model.Select`.

Code:

```
@model List<smartpond.Models.FeederPillar>
<table id="listing" 
       class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sl no</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>R Voltage</th>
            <th>Y Voltage</th>
            <th>B Voltage</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
        {
            <tr class="tr_@item.value.deviceid">
                <td>@(item.i + 1)</td>
                <td>@item.value.datetime</td>
                <td>@item.value.RVoltage</td>
                <td>@item.value.YVoltage</td>
                <td>@item.value.BVoltage</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: show your table in Database.

Comment: im calling the rest api and  showing the api response in the datatable, an also able to get the data in my datatable there is no issue with output, im just getting error while building the solution in .cshtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following using statement at the top of your razor page

```
@using System.Linq
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.id</td>
        <td>@item.datetime</td>
        <td>@item.RVoltage</td>
        <td>@item.YVoltage</td>
        <td>@item.BVoltage</td>
    </tr>
}
```